# Full Calendar day click and dropped the event date issue with Timezone change

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, fullcalendar, momentjs

I am using full-calendar for my calendar functionality. Everything is working fine with IST but when Timezone changed to PST the problem occurs.

Up to now, what I have done is

1) When user clicks on a calendar he/she can add an event for the clicked date and the modal popup will be selected with the date clicked date.

2) Same as above doing for drop function.

In both cases I am using a date parameter to get the clicked/dropped date in full-calendar

Following is the code snippet which I am using

**Javascirpt code to invoke calendar**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            eventSources: [

                {
                  url:'calendar/all_events',
                  type: 'POST',
                  data: {event_asset_id: $('#asset_id').val()},
                  error: function () {

                  },

                  textColor: 'black' // a non-ajax option
                }
            ],

            header: {
                left: 'prev',
                center: 'title, month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
                right: 'next'
            },
            editable: true,
            draggable: false,
            droppable: true,
            drop: function (date, jsEvent, ui) {
              //getting the dropped date from calendar
              var droppedDate = date._d
              console.log(droppedDate);
            },
          dayClick: function (date, jsEvent, view) {
             //getting the clicked date from calendar
              var clickedDate = date._d
              console.log(clickedDate);
            }
      });
  });
```

**HTML code for div replace with calendar**

```
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

What's the issue is when ever time zone changed to PST and user clicks/drops on 15-12-2015 on the calendar and when i console the date object it returns as follows

```
m {
_ambigTime: true
_ambigZone: true
_d: Mon Dec 14 2015 16:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)
_fullCalendar: true
_isAMomentObject: true
_isUTC: true
_locale: V.e
_fullCalendar_weekCalc: "local"
__proto__: l
_offset: 0
_pf: Object
__proto__: m
}
```

I don't have any idea why it fails in PST timezone. I am unable to find a solution.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be using the `_d` field.  FullCalendar returns a `moment` object, and `_d` and other fields prefixed with an underscore are internal to moment.

Instead, use the [display functions](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) available to you.  When you need a string, you should use the `format` function.

While you could use moment's `toDate` function to get a `Date` object, in this case you're not going to be satisfied with the results because you are using FullCalendar's default [ambiguously zoned](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/Moment/#ambiguously-zoned) mode.  Formatting a string for output is safer.  (See the examples on that page.)

Comment: It worked for me, i am getting correct date now with date object.. i changed code to get date, instead of `date._d` replaced with `date.format()` to get relevent format which i need.